# Error on SEO friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ listenAlbum.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/category/?$ category.php?name=$1
```

I am having this .htaccess file
when i try to open http://mywebsite.com/my-album it works perfect
but when i try to navigate on category page like this
http://mywebsite.com/category/category-name it give a 404 Not Found 
Can any one help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second RewriteRule if your `htaccess` says the URL should be `http://mywebsite.com/category-name/category/`.

Change your `htaccess` to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ listenAlbum.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ category.php?name=$1
```

Comment: I replaced the code with yours but it still not working

Comment: Sorry, I had the slash before `category` instead of after it, answer updated. I'm sure from my answer above you see where you were going wrong?